# How to achieve dynamic binding in WPF/MVVC C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am rather new to MVVC/wpf, having mostly worked with winforms.

What I want to accomplish is dynamic databinding without using code behind in WPF. The user interface consists of a devexpress grid and a couple of buttons. Each button press loads an object list and presents the objects in the grid. The lists contain different object types depending on the button pressed. For this example I have two classes to present: FatCat and FatDog.

In winforms this works:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((GridView)gridCtrl.MainView).Columns.Clear();
        gridCtrl.DataSource = new BindingSource(itsModel.GetAll<FatDog>(), null);
    }


    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((GridView)gridCtrl.MainView).Columns.Clear();
        gridCtrl.DataSource = new BindingSource(itsModel.GetAll<FatCat>(), null);
    }
```

I have configured the grid to create columns dynamically, so everything just works. itsModel is of type CatClientModel.

In wpf I have defined the DataContext to be CatClientModel.

What should I use for ItemsSource in the grid to achieve the same behaviour as my winforms solution?

dxg:GridControl ItemsSource="{Binding SomeDynamicList}"

In other words, what should SomeDynamicList be in the code above? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

I am, as I stated, using the DevExpress wpf grid control, but the question ought to be general and apply to any control presenting object lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In other words, what should `SomeDynamicList` be in the code above?

`SomeDynamicList` should be an `ObservableCollection<T>` property to which you can add any objects of type `T` that you want to display in the `GridControl`.

Set the `DataContext` of the `GridControl`, or any of its parent elements, to an instance of a class where this property is defined:

```
public class CatClientModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Animal> SomeDynamicList { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Animal>();
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new CatClientModel();
    }
}
```

> Ok. But the thing is that the ObservableCollection contains different types. Unfortunately there is no feasible class to inherit from. I want to bind to either ObservableCollection or ObservableCollection depending on which button was pressed

Switch the `DataContext` then, or change the property into an `IEnumerable` and set it to a new collection each time the button is clicked. This requires you to implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface in your view model

```
private System.Collections.IEnumerable _collection;
public System.Collections.IEnumerable MyProperty
{
    get { return _collection; }
    set { _collection = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
}
```

Comment: Ok. But the thing is that the ObservableCollection contains different types. If you compare to my winforms example each buttonpress creates a new strongly typed list. Unfortunately there is no feasible class to inherit from. The actual project I'm working on has nothing to do with animals, it is merely an example. So binding to ObservableCollection<Animal> does not solve the problem. I want to bind to either ObservableCollection<FatCat> or ObservableCollection<FatDog> depending on which button was pressed.

Comment: Switch the DataContext then, or change the property into an IEnumerable and set it to a new collection each time the button is clicked. This requires you to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface in your view model.

Comment: Is there a way to change the DataContext without code behind? How would changing the property to an IEnumerable help me?

Comment: 1.No. 2. You can set an IEnumerable property to either an ObservableCollection<A> or an ObservableCollection<B>.

Comment: I don't get how 2 would work. IEnumerable also requires the type at declaration time. Or?

Comment: IEnumerable is an interface that most built-in collections implement...

Comment: I know that. I just don't see how it would solve the problem since I have to explicitly state the type when declaring an IEnumerable. Please consider my winforms example. My question is whether that can be accomplished through datacontext and bindings in wpf without using code behind.

Comment: The compile-time *type* of the property should be IEnumerable. At runtime, you can set it to any collection that implements IEnumerable. See my sample code.

Comment: Pelle -- You do have to declare the type of a collection or a list or ... as each collection can contain only one type usually class definition. Most grids implement an itemsource that points to what the grid loads and you can have two collections and switch by defining where the item source points to, there is no feasable workaround for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use XAML to define which data sources your code maps to for each grid that is possible. That does require at least some method of MVVM manager either prism or mvvmlight to connect the view model to the view.

so if you do go the MVVM model route, the Model would contain a description for each of your grids like this:

```
 public BulkObservableCollection<icd10facet> FacetList
    {
        get { return this._facets; }
        set { SetProperty(ref this._facets, value); }

    }
    public INotifyTaskCompletion<BulkObservableCollection<PetsConvert>> ConceptList
    {
        get { return this._concept; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref this._concept, value);
        }
    }
```

In the XAML for your code the grid woud bind to the grid defined by ConceptList in this way:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ConceptList.Result}"
```

this answer does NOT address how to wire up Prism 6.0 for example to use a view model but for examples see:

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism

Which contains documentation and starter code. Keep in mind that there is not any specific reason that putting code in the code behind for the view is a problem, first solve the problem and then refactor if separation of concerns is an issue for you.

Using this technique you can bind each grid to its own data source. In the MVVM space buttons and other things use a commanding model to communicate with the view model.

```
 <Button Content="Load Rule Data" Width="100" Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5px" Command="{Binding LoadRuleData }"/>
```

this requires defining a command delegate in the viewmodel for LoadRuleData

```
    public DelegateCommand LoadRuleData { get; private set; }
```

and then (usually in the constructor) wire the DelegateCommand to the method that is going to do the work.

```
 this.LoadRuleData = new DelegateCommand(this.loadRules);
```